# Get raw element representation including open and close tags

Tags: xml, go

I know about golang xml `,innerxml` tag which allows getting the element inner content as a raw xml. But what I need is to get the whole element (open tag, inner content, close tag) as a raw data.

Here is a sample which I'd like to parse that way. I'd like to get the whole `<Useful>` with all its possible attributes element and avoid getting useless elements.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

const data = `<Document>
    <Useless1>
        blah-blah
    </Useless1>
    <Useless2>
        blah-blah
    </Useless2>
    <Useful someAttr="someVal">
        <InnerField1>Inner field 1 value</InnerField1>
        <InnerField2>Inner field 2 value</InnerField2>
        <InnerField3>Inner field 3 value</InnerField3>
    </Useful>
    <Useless3>
        blah-blah
    </Useless3>
</Document>
`

func main() {
    doc := Document{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &doc)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(doc.Useful.Data)
}

type Document struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Document"`
    Useful  struct {
        Data string `xml:",innerxml"`
    } `xml:"Useful"`
}
```

the link to the code in a playground is here:
https://goplay.space/#0KDXiRKDwlY

This is what I got:

```
    <InnerField1>Inner field 1 value</InnerField1>
    <InnerField2>Inner field 2 value</InnerField2>
    <InnerField3>Inner field 3 value</InnerField3>
```

And this is what I'd like to get:

```
<Useful someAttr="someVal">
    <InnerField1>Inner field 1 value</InnerField1>
    <InnerField2>Inner field 2 value</InnerField2>
    <InnerField3>Inner field 3 value</InnerField3>
</Useful>
```

Please note that the actual structure I'm working with is much more complex. I wouldn't like to get the whole `<Document>` inner content as a raw xml and then parse it trying to get rid of useless elements manually. The `<Useful>` part varies, so I can't hardcode e.g. attributes cause they can differ from one document to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Capturing attributes too

You may use an additional field in your `Useful` struct to capture all the attributes (of a slice of type [`xml.Attr`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Attr)) like this:

```
Useful  struct {
    Attrs []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
    Data  string     `xml:",innerxml"`
} `xml:"Useful"`
```

When adding another attrubute to `<Useful>`:

```
<Useful someAttr="someVal" someAttr2="someVal2">
    ...
<Useful>
```

And outputting the result with `fmt.Printf("%+v", doc.Useful)`, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zfmn7XM0t8K)):

```
{Attrs:[{Name:{Space: Local:someAttr} Value:someVal} {Name:{Space: Local:someAttr2} Value:someVal2}] Data:
        <InnerField1>Inner field 1 value</InnerField1>
        <InnerField2>Inner field 2 value</InnerField2>
        <InnerField3>Inner field 3 value</InnerField3>
    }
```

### Truly getting the complete raw XML

Another, more complex way would be to use [`xml.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) to read the input by tokens, and mark the position of the start and end of `<Useful>`. Then you can get the complete raw XML of `<Useful>`.

This is how it could look like:

```
dec := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))

var start, end int64
foundStart := false
for {
    if !foundStart {
        start = dec.InputOffset()
    }
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        break
    }
    if se, ok := t.(xml.StartElement); ok {
        if se.Name.Local == "Useful" {
            foundStart = true
        }
    }
    if se, ok := t.(xml.EndElement); ok {
        if se.Name.Local == "Useful" {
            end = dec.InputOffset()
            // We may break here, we got what we wanted
            break
        }
    }
}

fmt.Println(data[start:end])
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MLorvlFvoor)):

```
<Useful someAttr="someVal" someAttr2="someVal2">
        <InnerField1>Inner field 1 value</InnerField1>
        <InnerField2>Inner field 2 value</InnerField2>
        <InnerField3>Inner field 3 value</InnerField3>
    </Useful>
```

Since we don't process the content of `<Useful>`, we may speed this up by using [`Decoder.Skip()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Skip) like this:

```
dec := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))

var start, end int64
for {
    start = dec.InputOffset()
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        break
    }
    if se, ok := t.(xml.StartElement); ok {
        if se.Name.Local != "Useful" {
            continue
        }
        if err := dec.Skip(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
        end = dec.InputOffset()
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(data[start:end])
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/idIWKalPCKR).

Comment: another approach utilizing the unmarshaler interface https://play.golang.com/p/zQjALol_uXq

Comment: @mkopriva Post it as an alternative.